# transferring/downloading files to bucket within a google cloud bucket causes disconnection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download a file using `wget` into my GCP bucket, and just after the download is finished the following error shows:  `Transport endpoint is not connected`
Then the file is empty.

Using scp from my local machine also causes the same error. Then I have to unmount the bucket and mount it again. But I am unable to download files from external sources.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely "Transport endpoint is not connected" issue can be caused by [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) process being killed suddenly.

There are iterations of this error happening that have been fixed by [unmounting and mounting](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/79)

Cloud Storage FUSE is a Google-developed and [community-supported](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues) open-source tool, so if this issue keeps happening to you, you might want to ask for support there.